# Compiler Error Message: CS0246: when I renamed my project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I renamed my project and it would compile before but when I made some changes it stopped working for some reason

the error is

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Lab4' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I made a new project from the template of Lab4 and renamed it to lab5 following the steps here

http://petermcintyre.com/topics/using-an-app-as-a-template-asp-net-mvc/

I found the source file

```
Line 28:     using Lab4;
Line 29:     
Line 30:     

Source File: c:\Users\Albert\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4b806faf\de1f1e7\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.c_hu0onk.0.cs    Line: 28
```

of that but when I try to change the using Lab4 to lab5 and recompile it, the same error happens and that file gets deleted and a new one gets made with the same Lab4 issue.

Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 55):

When Visual Studio creates your project, it automatically adds its original namespace to `\Views\web.config`:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            ...
            ...
            ...
            <add namespace="OriginalProjectNamespace" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

After renaming the project or changing its default namespace you must manually change it in this file.

Comment: This is also true for web.config files in other Areas you may have set up.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a reference/path that VS hasn't updated when you renamed. It's quick and dirty but if you run a Grep against the solution folder for the old project name and replace it with the new one and then re-open and compile in VS it should solve your problem.

Comment: I did a cntrl h search in the solution explorer to try and replace Lab4 to lab5 but it says nothing could be found

Comment: Get out of VS, it will ignore many of the meta files in the solution. What you want to do is Grep the old project name in the entire folder (including system/hidden files) then open any it finds in notepad and change manually. Only once you've done that should you re-open and compile in VS. NB. ALWAYS BACKUP THE SOLUTION FIRST

Comment: Just to be double helpful if you're not familiar with Grep then google for BareGrep, it's a tiny program and very easy to use, you won't need instructions.

Comment: In addition, delete you `/bin` and `/obj` folders from within  your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the view folder, open the web config then change the namespace to the new namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you renamed your project using F2/Rename in Visual Studio and you're using .NET Core, also check:

```
/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml
```

Perform a deep search: (Ctrl + Shift + F), and in `Find what` add your old namespace. Inside `Look in`, select `Current Project (Including External Items)`.

This should show you more files that were not automatically renamed by Visual Studio. Manually rename the old namespace with the new one.

**Careful on blindly renaming everything!!!** Not because you renamed the project it means that it also renamed the folder structure!!! There are many references with old folder structures. I **strongly** recommend doing the renaming **gradually**

[image: Use Current Project Including External Items]

Answer (score 0):

for example if you have this error on Privacy.cshtml cs02046,
Just go to this razor page Privacy.cshtml, change @model PrivacyModel to [YOUR_RENAME_NAMESPACE].Pages.PrivacyModel